# Ruby's string.downcase! behavior

Tags: ruby

I am new to ruby and doing some basic string manipulation to get the hang of it and I noticed that `foo = 'foo'.downcase!` is not the same as downcasing after assigning a vale to `foo` like this:

```
foo = 'foo'.downcase!
if foo.include? 'foo'
    print 'bar'
end
```

This will result in an `NoMethodError`: `` undefined method `include?' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError) ``

While downcasing foo after the value has been assigned does not:

```
foo = 'foo'
foo.downcase!
if foo.include? 'foo'
    print 'bar'
end
```

I am sorry if this is a trivial question but a few minutes of googling didn't return anything fruitful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because [`String#downcase!`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/String.html#method-i-downcase-21) is a destructive method (hence the !) meaning it operates on the object in place. Since it changes the object itself, its return value isn't need. The Ruby designers decided that a good use of the return value would be to indicate if any changes were made.

> Downcases the contents of str, returning nil if no changes were made.

Your string is already lowercase, so `downcase!` returns `nil` which you then replace the variable with.

Answer (score 2):

[`String#downase!`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/String.html#method-i-downcase-21) returns `nil` if the change can't be done on the receiver *string object*. That's the reason `foo = 'foo'.downcase!` causes the local variable `foo` to be assginbed as `nil`. Because `foo` string is already dowcased.

That's why `if foo.include? 'foo'` became `if nil.include? 'foo'`. As we know `Nilclass#include?` doesn't exist, so you got the error.

But [`String#downcase`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/String.html#method-i-downcase) returns the receiver itself, if *no change can be done*, or *changed new string object* if change can be done.

In the below example :

The `downcase!` method returns `nil` (reason as I mentioned in the first paragraph), but as you didn't do *local variable assignment*, while you are calling the method (which is the case of your first example), thus `foo` still holding the original object `'foo'`.

```
foo = 'foo'
foo.downcase!
```

That's the reason `if foo.include? 'foo'` became `if "foo".include? "foo"`. But you are calling `#include?` on `'foo'` an instance of String and `String#include?` method exist, thus no error you got.

Answer (score 1):

You're seeing this behaviour because of this bit:

```
'foo'.downcase!
```

The `downcase!` method is an **in-place** substitution, meaning that it affects only the object that it was called on. It will only return a result when the string is changed. For example...

```
foo = 'foo'.downcase!    # foo == NilClass, because 'foo' is already lower-case.
bar = 'BAR'.downcase!    # bar == String, because 'BAR' was changed to 'bar'
```

If you need to guarantee that `foo` is a string after doing a downcase, you can use the non-intrusive `downcase` method (note the missing exclamation point).

```
foo = 'foo'.downcase
if foo.include? 'foo'
    print 'bar'
end
```

The above code should always work. As a rule, it's generally a good idea to work with strings as immutable, rather than using the intrusive methods, as it can simplify code quite a lot, and avoid bugs like this.